Laurent Series Expansion of $\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ about $z = 1$
I am working on the following exercise of computing the (1) Laurent series expansion and (2) radius of convergence.

Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z + 1)(z + 2)}$.
Consider the annular domain $3 < \lvert z - 1 \rvert < \infty$, where $f$ is analytic in.

Then, by decomposing into partial fractions, $f(z) = \frac{1}{z + 1} - \frac{1}{z + 2}$.
By using the geometric series expansion:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{z + 1} = \frac{1}{(z - 1) + 2} = \frac{1}{(z - 1)(1 - (-\frac{2}{z - 1}))} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cdot 2^n}{(z - 1)^{n + 1}} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} \cdot 2^{n - 1}}{(z - 1)^n} \\\\
&\frac{1}{z + 2} = \frac{1}{(z - 1) + 3} = \frac{1}{(z - 1)(1 + \frac{3}{z - 1})} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cdot 3^n}{(z - 1)^{n + 1}} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} \cdot 3^{n - 1}}{(z - 1)^n}
\end{align*}
$$
Then, we have the Laurent expansion (because $f$ is analytic in the annular domain):
$f(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty ((-1)^{n - 1} \cdot (2^{n - 1} - 3^{n - 1})) \frac{1}{(z - 1)^n}$.
Questions

In my work, I relied on the property that $\lvert z - 1 \rvert > 3 > 2$ to invoke the geometric series expansion. Are there other approaches?
Will it be possible to relax the constraints on the annular domain $r < \lvert z - 1 \rvert < \infty$ by choosing some $r < 3$ so that we can still invoke an expansion? My guess: I think not, because we should have $f$ analytic on the annular domain, and $f$ is analytic everywhere except $z = -1, -2$, so $\lvert z - 1 \rvert > 3$.
How to determine the radius of convergence of $f$, i.e., $a, b > 0$ such that $f$ converges in $a < \lvert z - 1 \rvert < b$?

I guess I can't apply Cauchy-Hadamard Formula here because the formula only works for power series.
I know that the Laurent series converges in a closed annulus inside $3 < \lvert z - 1 \rvert < \infty$. So, we can pick $b = \infty$. How do I pick $a$?




There's a similar way to get Laurent series on $\mid z\mid \lt2$ and on $2\lt\mid z\mid \lt3,$ I believe.

@calcll Thanks for your response, but I guess that will be an expansion around $z = 0$ and not $z = 1$?

Sorry, I meant $\mid z-1\mid$ where I wrote $\mid z\mid.$

Ah thanks! I think that will also work by using the geometric series expansion as well.

I think so.  Very similar.
